# How can i fix the problem in my solidity code? I started to learn solidity 2 days ago

Tags: solidity

this is my contract which using library.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./PriceConverter.sol";

contract Fundme{

    using PriceConverter for uint256;//引入Library PriceConverter到uint
    uint256 public minimumUsd=10 * 1e18;

    address[] public funders;
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;

    function fund() public payable {
    require(getConversionRate(msg.value)>=minimumUsd, "Didn't send enough!");
    funders.push(msg.sender);
    addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender]=msg.value; 


}
```

this is library

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

library PriceConverter{
    function getPrice() internal view returns(uint256) {
    //ABI
    //Address 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306);
    (,int256 price,,,)=priceFeed.latestRoundData(); 
    return uint(price*1e10);
}
function getVersion() internal view returns (uint256){
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed=AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306);
   return priceFeed.version();
}
function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) internal view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 ethprice = getPrice();
    uint256 ethAmountInUsd=(ethprice*ethAmount)/1e18;
    return ethAmountInUsd;
}
}
```

But I met the problem:getConversionRate is undeclared indentifier.

I changed getConversionRate(msg.value) to msg.value.getConversionRate() and the problem fixed. But why getConversionRate(msg.value) is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to access function `getConversionRate()` that is not available in this scope (directly from the `Fundme` contract). You need to specify the library name when calling the function:

```
require(PriceConverter.getConversionRate(msg.value)>=minimumUsd, "Didn't send enough!");
```

Answer (score -1):

There's another way to access the function, just use

```
require(address(this).getConversionRate(msg.value)>=minimumUsd, "Didn't send enough!");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).